# What's the logic to execute both if and else condition at the same time

Tags: c++, c

I had a question that how can you execute both the condition of if statement and else statement at same time?

For example

```
if(?) {
    printf("Hello");
} else {
    printf(" world");
}
```

and output should be `Hello world`

and what should be `condition` instead of `?`?

Comment: Don't use if-else?

Comment: You cannot do this without undefined behavior and tricking the compiler (or adding goto/outer loops, of course)

Comment: The whole point of an `if`/`else` is to do *one or the other*, not both.

Comment: if and else are mutually exclusive blocks, so if you want to perform both simply remove the if/else.

Comment: `if(condition | run_anyway) {} else if(!condition | run_anyway) {}`

Comment: The question is not that bad as it may seem, it could be the question on an exam in CS to explain multi-threading. (See my answer with fork() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200844/whats-the-logic-to-execute-both-if-and-else-condition-at-the-same-time/22203088#22203088 )

Comment: @Simson Yeah. I couldn't explain the question in a right way I guess.. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question makes no sense at all, because it contradicts the idea of if/else. There is no anyway! If you don't want if/else cases you don't need to use it.

Comment: @user3368369 Please add more detail to your question e.g. if it _is_ about multithreading, please mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is to *print* "Hello world" from this piece of code, you can do this trick:

```
if(!printf("Hello")) {
    printf("Hello"); //not reachable 
}
else {
    printf(" world");
}
```

Note that you **cannot** satisfy both `if` and `else`.

---

My piece of code **doesn't** print from the block inside the `if`, but from the *condition* itself. By "cannot satisfy both `if` and `else` I mean that if you have:

```
if(something) {
   doSomething();
} else {
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

There is no way that both `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` get executed.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain so I can avoid my mistakes in the future.

Comment: It worked !! What do you mean by cannot satisfy both if and else? Your piece of code just did that right? Or is there other explanation ? Please explain. @Maroun

Comment: @user3368369 The code never reached inside the `if` block. All it did was execute the `printf` in `if` condition and then enter the `else` block.

Comment: -"execute both the condition of if statement and else statement at same time"... and this does not do that...

Comment: @Johan Don't miss my explanation.

Comment: You are right, but this question is just so horrible...

Answer (score 4):

An alternative would be to fork your process, one thread will print "Hello" and the other one " world". However there is no guarantee the print will not be " worldHello" instead

```
 #include <stdio.h>


 main(){
    if(fork()) {
        printf("Hello");
    } else {
        printf(" world");
    }
 }
```

Comment: +1 the only change is the if(?) to if(fork()) and the printout will be "Hello world" most of the time...

Comment: If the OS puts the different processes on different CPU-cores then they could in theory execute at the "same time"...

Answer (score 3):

There is no logic. You can't do this.

C11 6.8.4.1 The if statement:

> In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to `0`.
>   In the `else` form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to `0`. If the first substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is not
>   executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the precompiler to redefine the language to do this

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 main(){
 #define if(x)
 #define else

    if(abc) {
        printf("Hello");
    } else {
        printf(" world");
    }
 #undef if
 #undef else
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(true) {
    printf("Hello");
    goto world:
} else {
    world:
    printf(" world");
}
```

Comment: This is just so bad, but it is "correct" C...

Answer (score 0):

The logical way to do this would be to break this out, for example:

```
if (condition1)
  print("Hello");

if (condition2)
  print(" world");
```

Then you can control whether one or both are printed (or none).